# Facing Problem in find out Customer Issue

Tags: custom

I have an ecommerce website , before 11 august i was getting a very good amount of orders but after that suddenly , orders reduced and my website got down abruptly . I got no clues in the logs . After that when i re hosted , customers session are very less and people are not going to checkout page . I have checked multiple times but not able to find out the issue . Kindly help me asap.

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: While moving to checkout, try to see the errors in your system.log/exception.log and your web-server log..You will get some hint there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a marketing issue nothing to do with Magento.

If your site is working that mean your Magento is working fine.

Check you Google Analytics or Webmasters tools

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply , I am getting the same of sessions . But bounce rate suddenly increased from what we are getting after 11 th august